# Maxima of a Poisson Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Show that the terms of the Poisson probability function P[X=k] reach their maxima when k is the largest integer less than or equal to the parameter lambda.

Can anyone help me with the proof of this? I am not sure on how to proceed with this one.

Comment: consider the ratio of successive terms